# Generate Enum in Java Client with Swagger

Tags: java, api, rest, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am trying to create an API using Swagger 2.0. I would like to generate an interactive documentation using SwaggerUI and also generate API clients (in Java, JavaScript...). I just tried to generate a small Java Client.

I have a problem with Enumerations... In Swagger I can write the following (YAML here, the problem is the same if directly writing JSON):

```
 definitions:
   MediumStatus:
     type: string
     enum:
       - CLOSED
       - OPEN_AVAILABLE
       - OPEN_NOT_AVAILABLE
       - NOT_AVAILABLE
```

In the generated Java Client, what is expect/want is something like:

```
public enum MediumType
{
CLOSED,
OPEN_AVAILABLE,
OPEN_NOT_AVAILABLE,
NOT_AVAILABLE;

public String value()
{
    return name();
}

public static MediumType fromValue(String v)
{
    return valueOf(v);
}
```

}

but the SwaggerCodegen generate a client with:

```
    @ApiModel(description = "")
    @javax.annotation.Generated(value = "class io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2015-12-21T14:03:23.470Z")
   public class MediumType   {

  @Override
  public String toString()  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class MediumType {\n");

    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

This class is not really correct, it don't even contains the enum values !

Can someone can tell me what I am missing ?

EDIT/

Problem sovlded with https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/1740

Comment: There's a recent PR supporting Enum class merged into master: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/1740. Please pull the latest swagger-codegen to give it a try.

Comment: @wing328 Problem solved with this PR ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with this commit: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/1740